# Sorting XML with XSLT - entire XML-schema is not known

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

I am wondering whether XSLT makes it possible to sort an XML file if I don't know the entire XML-schema.

For example I would like to sort the following XML file.
*Sort /CATALOG/CD elements by /CATALOG/CD/TITLE*

```
<CATALOG attrib1="value1">
  <DVD2>
    <TITLE>The Godfather2</TITLE>
  </DVD2>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD attrib4="value4">
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>
      <CATALOG>
        <CD><TITLE>E</TITLE></CD>
        <CD><TITLE>I</TITLE></CD>
        <CD><TITLE>D</TITLE></CD>
      </CATALOG>
    </PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD attrib2="value2">
    <TITLE attrib3="value3">Greatest Hits</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <DVD>
    <TITLE>The Godfather1</TITLE>
  </DVD>
</CATALOG>
```

The output should be:

```
<CATALOG attrib1="value1">
  <CD attrib4="value4">
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>
      <CATALOG>
        <CD><TITLE>E</TITLE></CD>
        <CD><TITLE>I</TITLE></CD>
        <CD><TITLE>D</TITLE></CD>
      </CATALOG>
    </PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD attrib2="value2">
    <TITLE attrib3="value3">Greatest Hits</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <DVD2>
    <TITLE>The Godfather2</TITLE>
  </DVD2>
  <DVD>
    <TITLE>The Godfather1</TITLE>
  </DVD>
</CATALOG>
```

The following is one of the many tries I did:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!--<CATALOG>-->
    <xsl:for-each select="CATALOG/CD">
      <xsl:sort select="TITLE" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!--</CATALOG>-->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that, with this XSLT, XML parts outside the CD list are not displayed.
I could uncomment the two commented-out parts of code, but that's exactly what I want to avoid.
In that case if any attributes are added to the CATALOG element, they would not be copied to output XML.
I don't want to re-build the XML file: I just want to do a sort knowing exact information only about some part of the XML-schema.

This functionality is easy to implement for example using .NET (with XmlDocument and XmlNode objects), or Python's lxmx library, but is it possible with XSLT?

Thanks!

Note: It is not easy to find a sample input XML which will avoid misunderstanding the question in all cases. But I will try to detail the problem as much as I can:

- only CD elements right under CATALOG should be sorted (for example CD elements under the Bob Dylan section should be left untouched)
- it is all the same whether elements other than CD (for example DVD and DVD2) are in the beginning or end of the list
- no elements, attributes, values, comments, so nothing should be missing from the output XML
- non-CD elements (for example DVD and DVD2) should not be sorted by the TITLE subelement

Comment: Sorry. Because of weak phrasing, it was not clear that I only want to sort CD elements. So I had to edit the question a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping on the line of just modifying the identity transformation (which might not be really safe), I think that the following should be equivalent to @Tim's answer.

**NOTE** I'm not promoting this technique at all, unless you understand what's the general behavior of the identity transformation.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* 
                | node()[not(self::CD[parent::CATALOG])]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="CD[parent::CATALOG]">
                <xsl:sort select="TITLE"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or, if you care about the  other elements `DVD` and `DVD2`, you can do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="CD[parent::CATALOG]">
                <xsl:sort select="TITLE"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()
                [not(self::CD[parent::CATALOG])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you eventually explain the problem with this transform?

Comment: Sorry. I have modified the original question a little bit now. Because you are the second person who misunderstands it.

Comment: mmm, that's exactly what my transform does. What's the problem?

Comment: It would not, if there were not only CD elements under CATALOG.

Comment: I see, just because I'm interested in the correctness of my answer here, I've changed it to provide a correct answer even if you are already ok with that of @Tim.

Comment: The result of this transform is that it sorts all by element name (at all levels) and then by TITLE (at all levels). If it's a side effect depends by your requirements.

Comment: Added also a simplified version of the transform accepted as an answer. Cheers

Comment: In many cases, this functionality would be enough. So thanks! But obviously if the XML-schema defines e.g. that the CATALOG element must contain DVD, CD and BLUERAY elements in this specific order, then it would not be enough.

Comment: What modification did you make? (I cannot see any. Maybe because Tim C first has to accept it?)

Comment: Sure would be enough. The point is, you can always perform sort directly in the identity transformation. Did you see the last part of my answer? You can easily extend it to manage DVD, CD and BLUERAY specific order.

Comment: Okay, your last XSLT version looks indeed simpler and briefer than the answer accepted, and seems to work properly. I need time to do some more testing. Is it possible to remove empty lines without strip-pace?

Comment: What do you mean with "empty lines" and why you want to use some other thing if strip-space works? :)

Comment: Because output indenting does not work together with strip-space. Tim C needed to change only 4-5 characters in his code to achieve this goal. But I didn't succeed in modifying your code on the analogy of that change

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see any difference between my solution and the other in terms of the results, except I added strip-space. You may solve your problem simply removing that. Indentantion and strip-space should never conflicts each other.

Comment: Your code is functionally appropriate. Empty lines are just a flaw. It's just that I am always worried if these kinds of flaws hide some other unknown error. Anyway I don't understand why you say, strip-space and output-indenty-yes don't conflict. The xsl:output element in your XSLT is just simply ignored (because of xsl:strip-space). Even if I change the order of these two elements.

Comment: Oh well, was not my intention change your mind about acceptance. However, you are welcome.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I just needed time for testing. Sorry for complaining about the formatting. It turned out that I'd been using the wrong XSLT processor, other XSLT processors interpret those two elements properly. - However, it turned out that your XSLT code fragment does not work properly if I replace the word "TITLE" with any other element name under CD. So this approach might be wrong

Comment: Ok, you are true, but you also know that you have added requirements to your question by comments. that's confuses answerers most of the time. I've now provided a _general rule_ which explains you how to perform sort of xml documents at different levels and inside different nodes leaving input document unchanged in its content. Cheers

Comment: The funny part is that it has turned out that this solution is not 100% perfect either. If I replace the inner content of one of the "/CATALOG/CD/TITLE" elements with "<CD><ARTIST>b</ARTIST></CD><CD><ARTIST>a</ARTIST></CD>", then this inner list of CD elements will be sorted as well. - I know it looks like I am always just trying to find bugs in the implementation, but in fact all I want is just to improve my XSLT competency.

Comment: @user, yes there are side effects there, it really depends from the input XML. Given the assumption in the question it is correct.

Comment: So you suggest that i should have written _Sort CD elements **directly** under CATALOG by TITLE_. It is just impossible to ask a question so perfectly. In this case you can always find out something. For example _did you mean by TITLE element or by TITLE attribute?_.

Comment: What do you mean with replace /CATALOG/CD/TITLE with ...? Which Inner list? Sorted by what? I'm sorry but I'm little lost with a 2-months old question which arise always reformulated :). If you have still trouble,  please edit your question with new challenging problems or create a new question. Thanks for your feedback. I've found this solution useful lot of times, but not perfect, most of all if the XML input changes.

Comment: Did you find the problems in the other solutions as well?

Comment: Because we are using here the identity transformation to perform sort you must be extremely precise if your input document is not :). So, for instance, I would use `<xsl:apply-templates select="CD[parent::CATALOG]">` in place of `<xsl:apply-templates select="CD">`. This ensures that you apply the templates only to the `CD` elements child of `CATALOG`.

Comment: Answering to the question _whether other solutions have the same problem_: Only you and Tim C have provided a solution. Actually in this specific case Tim C's XSLT does not fail, but it does not mean that that is 100% perfect. Lately I have only been studying your solution because it seems briefer, and you are pretty active here (thanks again!).

Comment: Pretty active here, it does not mean never failing ;-). Ok, working on a solution given your new details and telling you something more possibly.

Comment: Okay. I have tried your last proposal. In this case I also had to add a new node: `<xsl:apply-templates select="CD[not(parent::CATALOG)]" />`. But ... I think, if possible, we should define the criterion a little more precisely. _Not enough that the name of the parent element is CATALOG. This parent element should be the root element within the XML._

Comment: Ok, see my edited answer. I would say it is _logically equivalent_ to @Tim's one. What do you think?

Comment: Please use a [chat] room for extended discussions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is this a job for the identity transform? This can be used to copy XML whose schema is not known

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think all you need is to add a new template to match the CATALOG element, and then you can take some overriding action in this (in your case, to sort the CD elements)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="CATALOG">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="CD">
            <xsl:sort select="TITLE"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name() != 'CD']" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, when matching CATALOG, you can still copy any attributes, and any non-CD children in the schema, without explicitly knowing their names. Note that if there are DVD elements until CATALOG for example, these will all be moved after the sorted CD elements in this case.

Comment: At first sight, this solution is appropriate. I am doing some more testing and analyzing. Thanks!

Comment: Under CATALOG element after CD elements and before all the other elements, there are a lot of empty lines. Do you think it would be possible to remove them? I don't quite understand Kragen's XSLT code, but I think he has solved this specific problem.

Comment: I've replaced the select="node()[..." clause with select="*[..." if you want to give it another go.

Comment: I think your last modification made the solution pretty much complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get all attributes in `CATALOG` element you can write:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="CATALOG">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>

            <xsl:copy-of select="CD[1]/preceding-sibling::*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="CD">
                <xsl:sort select="TITLE"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:copy-of select="CD[last()]/following-sibling::*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<CATALOG atr1="value1" atr2="value2">
    <DVD>
        <FORMAT>DVD-9</FORMAT>
    </DVD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1999</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
    </CD>
    ...
    <BLUERAY>
        <TITLE>Contact</TITLE>
        <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
    </BLUERAY>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: Your plus line of code and the additional few modifications may take us closer to the solution.
But if I, for example, add an element with name "DVD" under "CATALOG", this new element will be ignored.

Comment: By "ignored" I mean "excluded". It's all the same whether the DVD element will be added to the beginning or the end of the list. But it should be included in output XML.

Comment: @user834929: See, I think that you can use deep copy with `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` axes to get such elements. However I am not sure is it best-efficient way (for large XML documents).

Comment: If I do the exact same modifictions you did, it still does not work. The result XML would contain BLUERAY and DVD elements as well, but CD elements are not sorted.

Comment: You're right, sorry for that. Try changing to `CD[1]/preceding-sibling::*` and `CD[last()]/following-sibling::*`.

Comment: The problem here is that if non-CD elements exist among CD elements, these non-CD elements will be excluded from output. This XSLT works  only if non-CD elements exist at the beginning or the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CATALOG">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *">
        <xsl:sort select="TITLE" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the standard copy template `match="@* | node()"` plus a special case for the `CATALOG` node where a sort criteria is specified.

Note that I've made the selector for the `apply-templates` rule inside the secod template slightly different from the standard copy template (`@* | *`).  This is because the standard copy template selector also includes text nodes, however text nodes have no `TITLE` element and so the sort directive ends up putting them all first which looks a bit weird (try it and see).

Comment: This XSLT sorts all nodes under CATALOG by TITLE. Elements having no TITLE are put at the beginning of the list. Actually it is a little confusing for me, because my aim was a little bit different. Anyway, you were mentioning something about "text nodes". Is that about removing empty lines from output XML?

Comment: What is your aim?  Text nodes are nodes in the XML dom that consist of only text.  For example `1999 Grammy Nominees` (inside the `Title` element) is a text node, however so is the whitespace between nodes.  Using `node()` (which includes text nodes) means that all text nodes are copied to the start of the `CATALOG` element - try it and see what I mean.

Comment: My aim is to only sort CD elements under CATALOG. (Other elements may be placed at the beginning or end of the list.)

Comment: So basically Tim C's solution is appropriate. The only problem with that, which I think you could solve, is that the output XML contains too much empty lines (whitespaces).

Comment: @user834929: Try using `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski: Thanks. This idea is good in 50%. I could not succeed in applying indentation together with this element.